# How to "use another-file" in rust? Module with hyphens in it

Tags: rust

Using `another_file` with underscore in as word separators works fine in Rust.

How do i use hyphens instead (`another-file.rs`)?

```
// another-file.rs
pub fn method() { }
```

```
// lib.rs
use another_file;        // <-- ERROR can not find another_file.rs
another_file::method();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will have to explicitly declare the module and [provide its path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.35.0/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute):

```
#[path="../path/to/another-file.rs"]
mod another_file;

use another_file;
```

However this is not common, and I wouldn't recommand it. Just stick with snake_case for module names.

Comment: Very simple and straight. My look like this of `#[path="./exercises/httpbin_request.rs"]` and of course I am in `src dir`. Thanks bro.